# jQuery datatable clears radio button in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, datatables

I have a jQuery Datatable with 3 headers. One header contains two radio buttons, another header contains a select box. By default, one of the options is checked.

When I use the search function in the Datatable to search for specific records, it does not display which radio button was checked. I inspected the DOM after I used the datatable search, and the input element still contains the CHECKED attribute. The select box is not affected. It still retains the value of the select box.

Also, IE behaves fine. O_o FF and Chrome are not recognizing the checked value.

I tried a `$(selector).datatable().fnDraw();`... no dice.

How do I get the datatable to recognize the checked attribute after, or during, the search? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: After further investigation, it looks like the fnDraw is clearing the value of the radio button.

**Code**

Initialize datatable **(Javascript)**

```
$.get('store_handler.ashx', { cmd: '9', pubId: pubId, sub: sub }, function(o) {
    $("#researchTableDiv").html(o.datatableContent);

    $('#ResearchTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sScrollY": "450px",
        "bSort": false
    });

    if (o.radioCheck == "single")
        $('#radioSingle').attr("checked", "checked");
    else
        $('#radioSub').attr("checked", "checked");

}, "json");
```

HTML of datatable headers **(C# .Net)**

```
    htmlString.Append("<thead>");
    htmlString.Append("<tr>");
    htmlString.Append("<th valign=\"middle\" style=\"width: 200px; text-align: left;valign:top;border-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px\" class=\"header\">Filter:&nbsp;");
    htmlString.Append("<select name=\"nonSort2\" style=\"height:20px;padding:0px;margin-top:-0px;font-size:11px\">");
    htmlString.Append("<option value=\"AKLPH\">All</option>");
    htmlString.Append("<option value=\"-\">---------------</option>");
    htmlString.Append("<option value=\"AK\">Alaska</option>");
    htmlString.Append("<option value=\"AL\">Etc...</option>");
    htmlString.Append("</select>");
    htmlString.Append("</th>");
    htmlString.Append("<th align=\"left\" class=\"header\" >");
    if (sub == "0")
    {
        htmlString.Append("<input type=\"radio\" value=\"0\" name=\"rdoSubscription\" id=\"radioSingle\" checked=\"CHECKED\" style=\"margin-left:1px\"/>Single Report");
        htmlString.Append("<input type=\"radio\" value=\"1\" name=\"rdoSubscription\" id=\"radioSub\" onclick=\"getPubDetails('" + pubId + "','1');\" style=\"margin-left:1px\"/>Subscription");
        jOut.Put("radioCheck", "single");
    }
    else
    {
        htmlString.Append("<input type=\"radio\" value=\"0\" name=\"rdoSubscription\" id=\"radioSingle\" onclick=\"getPubDetails('" + pubId + "','0');\" style=\"margin-left:1px\"/>Single Report");
        htmlString.Append("<input type=\"radio\" value=\"1\" name=\"rdoSubscription\" id=\"radioSub\" checked=\"CHECKED\" style=\"margin-left:1px\"/>Subscription");
        jOut.Put("radioCheck", "sub");
    }
    htmlString.Append("</th>");
    htmlString.Append("<th class=\"header\" align=\"center\">Action</th>");
    htmlString.Append("</tr>");
    htmlString.Append("</thead>");
```

Comment: Do you have any supporting code that you could provide to assist with your issue?

Comment: @Ant: i just made a fast search in the dataTables.js and found something like "jqFilter", there is where the search action happens

Comment: This is a legit question...why is it flagged as community wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the radio button after the draw event:

```
$.get('store_handler.ashx', { cmd: '9', pubId: pubId, sub: sub }, function(o) {
$("#researchTableDiv").html(o.datatableContent);

$('#ResearchTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sScrollY": "450px",
    "bSort": false,
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
      if (o.radioCheck == "single")
        $('#radioSingle').attr("checked", "checked");
      else
        $('#radioSub').attr("checked", "checked");
      }
   }
});


}, "json");
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you sooo much for your help! I figured it was something simple enough!

Comment: I am using "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                  $('.checked input:radio:checked').attr("checked","checked");
                }, but it is not working

Comment: @عثمانغني You need to correct your selector ;-) $('input[checked]').attr("checked","checked");

Answer (score 1):

I *just* had a similar problem, and solved it by reading the issue in red on [this link](http://datatables.net/faqs#ss_events). Maybe it can help you, maybe not, but hopefully it can.

Answer (score 1):

I build a lot of DataTables in my applications, but it seems like in a way you're attempting to "brute force" a server side solution.  Technically, what you're doing is a dom-based table because you're outputting HTML and having DataTables format it, though it appears from the `$.get` that you could be trying to leverage a server-side solution.  Server side is actually far more efficient because the server is limiting what it sends to the jQuery and lessening the need to deal with hundreds (or in my case millions) of records at once.  Obviously, it's also faster to take a raw json stream and build a table rather than having to traverse dom structure to get the same information.

I'd suggest trying a true server side solution.....for the sole reason that the data comes straight from your server-side technology of choice and doesn't get heavily manipulated as it obviously is here.  So, first, setup your a file (perhaps your store_handler.ashx) to output what you need in JSON (the most efficient transfer method for this operation)  The string should look something like this:

```
{"sEcho": 1, "iTotalRecords": 1, "iTotalDisplayRecords": 1, "aaData":[["one", "for", "each", "column"]]}
```

Make sure when doing this that you get your JSON outputting to screen first, and test it to ensure validity via [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Then, the jQuery would look something like this:

```
$('#detailstable').dataTable( {                                             
  "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "handler.ashx",
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  "bLengthChange": true,
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bSort": true,
  "iDisplayLength": 10,
  "bInfo": true,
  "aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "One", "sWidth": "15%" , "sClass":"center"},
    { "sTitle": "For", "sWidth": "15%" , "sClass":"center"},
    { "sTitle": "Each", "sWidth": "15%", "sClass":"center" },
    { "sTitle": "Column", "sWidth": "15%" , "sClass":"center"}
  ],
      "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    var something = $('#something').val();
    var somethingelse = $('#somethingelse').val();
    aoData.push(    { "name": "something", "value": something       },
            { "name": "somethingelse", "value": somethingelse   }
    );
    $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
    } );
   }
  });
```

-- edit --
I added the fnServerData section which is a callback that sends data to the query.  In the example given, it will make the variables something and somethingelse available in a $_REQUEST string to be used in the query.  You could use this to get the values of the selected fields back to the query to give you results.
-- edit --

Now, for the searching, you would have to add some elements to your source page to handle sorting/filtering/searching/etc.  This is a lot simpler than it sounds...each variable is passed via a $_REQUEST variable.  Check the [tutorial online](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) for an example of what comes in and how to sort on it.  Yes, the tutorial is in PHP, but the important part is figuring what values it's passing you and from that you can build your query accordingly.  Ignore the PHP specific elements of the tut.  We can help you out if it's still confusing.

Voila...more efficient, less confusing, and doing nearly exactly what you're talking about works in my applications without a problem.  No javascript voodoo required.

Comment: this is a great answer. i appreciate the advice and will definitely consider switching to json. however, do you think switching to json will solve my problem?

Comment: Regardless, I think this is a more direct and cleaner method of achieving your goal.  I'm going to edit the answer to add a part that adds lookup values to the Ajax query.  I use this method to build a datatable based on input text values (for instance to sort by various fields or do complex searches) and it should be able to filter based on your fields (as opposed to just passing them on the request string)  One unrelated issue I'd double check...some browsers have some quirks with "selected" triggers.  See this:  http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design/html-and-css/threads/66735